# What is correct way of forwarding Standard HTTP and HTTPS ports to another

Tags: ssl, portforwarding, forwarding

- I have a SSL server started on port 8080.

  - I want to redirect all browser requests to this port 
    from 80 (http://...) and from 443 (https://...)

Should I do 
1) 80 forward to 8080; 443 forward to 8080 or 
2) 80 forward to 443; 443 forward to 8080

Is there any difference in these approaches and what is correct?

Thanks!

Comment: What web server?  Is it your intent to force using HTTPS for all requests?

Comment: - web server - nginx
>> your intent to force using HTTPS for all requests 
- yes (because I have js application on the sub-domain (SSL) and want to have everything under same protocol to avoid JS problems with multi-domains)